# Can someone please help figure out this kernel panic report? I have been having these panics almost daily

Tags: imac, kernel-panic

So far it is happening randomly, the "BSD process name" line reflects different apps each time. I only use a few apps regularly - firefox, vlc, transmission, calendar, itunes. Is this a known issue with the 2017 iMac 21.5" line or Catalina 10.15.5?  Will updating to Big Sur solve my problem? Thanks in advance.

```
 panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff8011a4aa3a): Kernel trap at 0xffffff7f948bb340, type 14=page fault, registers:
    CR0: 0x000000008001003b, CR2: 0x0000000000000008, CR3: 0x00000001d408514f, CR4: 0x00000000003626e0
    RAX: 0x0000000000000000, RBX: 0xffffff80399e4000, RCX: 0x0037378a00000000, RDX: 0xffffff8110e65000
    RSP: 0xffffff9145cd3930, RBP: 0xffffff9145cd3960, RSI: 0x0037378a0000000a, RDI: 0xffffff80374bd000
    R8:  0x0000000000373789, R9:  0x0000000000000000, R10: 0x0000020000011000, R11: 0x00000000101a0009
    R12: 0xffffff81155c4030, R13: 0x0000000000000000, R14: 0xffffff80399e4650, R15: 0x0000000000000000
    RFL: 0x0000000000010206, RIP: 0xffffff7f948bb340, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000010
    Fault CR2: 0x0000000000000008, Error code: 0x0000000000000002, Fault CPU: 0x0, PL: 0, VF: 0

    Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
    0xffffff9145cd3390 : 0xffffff801191f5cd 
    0xffffff9145cd33e0 : 0xffffff8011a58b05 
    0xffffff9145cd3420 : 0xffffff8011a4a68e 
    0xffffff9145cd3470 : 0xffffff80118c5a40 
    0xffffff9145cd3490 : 0xffffff801191ec97 
    0xffffff9145cd3590 : 0xffffff801191f087 
    0xffffff9145cd35e0 : 0xffffff80120c27cc 
    0xffffff9145cd3650 : 0xffffff8011a4aa3a 
    0xffffff9145cd37d0 : 0xffffff8011a4a738 
    0xffffff9145cd3820 : 0xffffff80118c5a40 
    0xffffff9145cd3840 : 0xffffff7f948bb340 
    0xffffff9145cd3960 : 0xffffff7f947a351e 
    0xffffff9145cd39a0 : 0xffffff7f947a3a4f 
    0xffffff9145cd39d0 : 0xffffff7f947b267d 
    0xffffff9145cd3a10 : 0xffffff7f948c2706 
    0xffffff9145cd3a40 : 0xffffff7f947a100b 
    0xffffff9145cd3ac0 : 0xffffff801205695e 
    0xffffff9145cd3b10 : 0xffffff8012054be7 
    0xffffff9145cd3b60 : 0xffffff801205dcb3 
    0xffffff9145cd3ca0 : 0xffffff8011a082b2 
    0xffffff9145cd3db0 : 0xffffff8011925328 
    0xffffff9145cd3e10 : 0xffffff80118fbcc5 
    0xffffff9145cd3e70 : 0xffffff8011912aa2 
    0xffffff9145cd3f00 : 0xffffff8011a30d05 
    0xffffff9145cd3fa0 : 0xffffff80118c6226 
          Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
             com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2(438.5.4)[D695D9DA-7C20-35D6-910F-E7A332A0F515]@0xffffff7f9479a000->0xffffff7f9485efff
                dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity(1.0.5)[E35D090D-DB9E-3DD0-9723-651FA730AA13]@0xffffff7f9299d000
                dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[BE052F4D-9B80-3FCD-B36D-BACB7DEE0DF2]@0xffffff7f92331000
                dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOSurface(269.11)[F1E7389D-2807-3C5D-8A7F-5422542E867F]@0xffffff7f94768000
                dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(576.1)[B1C0006F-E1F5-37D9-9548-5F918E92B422]@0xffffff7f92cf0000
                dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily(47)[1FB49168-0280-3F04-A99A-F830C915E994]@0xffffff7f926cc000
             com.apple.driver.AppleIntelKBLGraphics(14.0.6)[E09E2681-5119-37A7-9975-B87BC4E1AA8F]@0xffffff7f94873000->0xffffff7f94968fff
                dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[BE052F4D-9B80-3FCD-B36D-BACB7DEE0DF2]@0xffffff7f92331000
                dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOSurface(269.11)[F1E7389D-2807-3C5D-8A7F-5422542E867F]@0xffffff7f94768000
                dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(576.1)[B1C0006F-E1F5-37D9-9548-5F918E92B422]@0xffffff7f92cf0000
                dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2(438.5.4)[D695D9DA-7C20-35D6-910F-E7A332A0F515]@0xffffff7f9479a000
    
    BSD process name corresponding to current thread: Transmission
    
    Mac OS version:
    19F101
    
    Kernel version:
    Darwin Kernel Version 19.5.0: Tue May 26 20:41:44 PDT 2020; root:xnu-6153.121.2~2/RELEASE_X86_64
    Kernel UUID: 54F1A78D-6F41-32BD-BFED-4381F9F6E2EF
    Kernel slide:     0x0000000011600000
    Kernel text base: 0xffffff8011800000
    __HIB  text base: 0xffffff8011700000
    System model name: iMac18,1 (Mac-4B682C642B45593E)
    System shutdown begun: NO
    Panic diags file available: YES (0x0)
    
    System uptime in nanoseconds: 125835522459836
    last loaded kext at 9798531479608: >usb.cdc.acm 5.0.0 (addr 0xffffff7f9545b000, size 32768)
    loaded kexts:
    |SCSITaskUserClient 422.120.3
    >!AMikeyHIDDriver   131
    >!ATopCaseHIDEventDriver    3430.1
    >!A!BMultitouch 97
    >AudioAUUC  1.70
    @fileutil   20.036.15
    @filesystems.autofs 3.0
    >!APlatformEnabler  2.7.0d0
    >AGPM   111.4.4
    >X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
    >!AUpstreamUserClient   3.6.8
    >!AHDAHardwareConfigDriver  283.15
    >!AHDA  283.15
    >!AGraphicsDevicePolicy 5.2.4
    >!A!IKBLGraphics    14.0.6
    @AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics   5.2.4
    >!AHV   1
    |IOUserEthernet 1.0.1
    |IO!BSerialManager  7.0.5f6
    >pmtelemetry    1
    >!AGFXHDA   100.1.428
    >AGDCBacklightControl   5.2.4
    |Broadcom!B20703USBTransport    7.0.5f6
    >!AFIVRDriver   4.1.0
    @Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X    7.0.0
    >!ABacklight    180.3
    >ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
    >!A!IKBLGraphicsFramebuffer 14.0.6
    >!AThunderboltIP    3.1.4
    >!ASMCLMU   212
    >!A!ISlowAdaptiveClocking   4.0.0
    >eficheck   1
    >!AMCCSControl  1.14
    >!A!IPCHPMC 2.0.1
    |IO!BUSBDFU 7.0.5f6
    >!AFileSystemDriver 3.0.1
    >!AVirtIO   1.0
    @filesystems.hfs.kext   522.100.5
    @!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeDataless    1.0.0d1
    @BootCache  40
    @!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeZlib    1.0.0
    @filesystems.apfs   1412.120.2
    >!ASDXC 1.7.7
    |!ABCM5701Ethernet  10.3.5
    >AirPort.BrcmNIC    1400.1.1
    @private.KextAudit  1.0
    >!AAHCIPort 341.0.2
    >!AACPIButtons  6.1
    >!ARTC  2.0
    >!ASMBIOS   2.1
    >!AACPIEC   6.1
    >!AAPIC 1.7
    $!AImage4   1
    @nke.applicationfirewall    303
    $TMSafetyNet    8
    @!ASystemPolicy 2.0.0
    |EndpointSecurity   1
    >usb.cdc.acm    5.0.0
    >usb.serial 6.0.0
    >usb.cdc.ecm    5.0.0
    >usb.cdc.ncm    5.0.0
    >!UMergeNub 900.4.2
    >!AHIDKeyboard  209
    >!AHS!BDriver   3430.1
    >IO!BHIDDriver  7.0.5f6
    >!AMultitouchDriver 3440.1
    >!AInputDeviceSupport   3440.8
    @kext.triggers  1.0
    >DspFuncLib 283.15
    @kext.OSvKernDSPLib 529
    >!AGraphicsControl  5.2.4
    |IOAVB!F    850.1
    >!ASSE  1.0
    >!AHDA!C    283.15
    |IOHDA!F    283.15
    |Broadcom!BHost!CUSBTransport   7.0.5f6
    |IO!BHost!CUSBTransport 7.0.5f6
    |IO!BHost!CTransport    7.0.5f6
    |IO!B!F 7.0.5f6
    |IO!BPacketLogger   7.0.5f6
    >!ABacklightExpert  1.1.0
    |IONDRVSupport  576.1
    >IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
    >X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
    |IOAccelerator!F2   438.5.4
    @!AGPUWrangler  5.2.4
    @!AGraphicsDeviceControl    5.2.4
    |IOSlowAdaptiveClocking!F   1.0.0
    >!AThunderboltEDMSink   4.2.3
    >!AThunderboltDPOutAdapter  6.2.6
    >!ASMBus!C  1.0.18d1
    |IOGraphics!F   576.1
    >IOPlatformPlugin!F 6.0.0d8
    >!ASMBusPCI 1.0.14d1
    @plugin.IOgPTPPlugin    840.3
    >usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.2
    >!UAudio    323.1
    >usb.cdc    5.0.0
    >usb.networking 5.0.0
    >usb.!UHostCompositeDevice  1.2
    |IOAudio!F  300.2
    @vecLib.kext    1.2.0
    |IOSerial!F 11
    |IOSurface  269.11
    @filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext 1
    >!AThunderboltDPInAdapter   6.2.6
    >!AThunderboltDPAdapter!F   6.2.6
    >!AThunderboltPCIDownAdapter    2.5.4
    >!AHPM  3.4.4
    >!A!ILpssI2C!C  3.0.60
    >!A!ILpssDmac   3.0.60
    >!A!ILpssI2C    3.0.60
    >!AXsanScheme   3
    >!AThunderboltNHI   5.8.6
    |IOThunderbolt!F    7.6.1
    |IOEthernetAVB!C    1.1.0
    |IO80211!F  1200.12.2b1
    >mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
    >corecapture    1.0.4
    |IOSkywalk!F    1
    |IONVMe!F   2.1.0
    >!A!ILpssGspi   3.0.60
    |IOAHCI!F   290.0.1
    >usb.!UXHCIPCI  1.2
    >usb.!UXHCI 1.2
    >usb.!UHostPacketFilter 1.0
    |IOUSB!F    900.4.2
    >!AEFINVRAM 2.1
    >!AEFIRuntime   2.1
    |IOSMBus!F  1.1
    |IOHID!F    2.0.0
    $quarantine 4
    $sandbox    300.0
    @kext.!AMatch   1.0.0d1
    >DiskImages 493.0.0
    >!AFDEKeyStore  28.30
    >!AEffaceable!S 1.0
    >!AKeyStore 2
    >!UTDM  489.120.1
    |IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice  422.120.3
    >!ACredentialManager    1.0
    >KernelRelayHost    1
    >!ASEPManager   1.0.1
    >IOSlaveProcessor   1
    |IOUSBMass!SDriver  157.121.1
    |IOSCSIArchitectureModel!F  422.120.3
    |IO!S!F 2.1
    |IOUSBHost!F    1.2
    >!UHostMergeProperties  1.2
    >usb.!UCommon   1.0
    >!ABusPower!C   1.0
    |CoreAnalytics!F    1
    >!AMobileFileIntegrity  1.0.5
    @kext.CoreTrust 1
    |IOTimeSync!F   840.3
    |IONetworking!F 3.4
    |IOReport!F 47
    >!AACPIPlatform 6.1
    >!ASMC  3.1.9
    >watchdog   1
    |IOPCI!F    2.9
    |IOACPI!F   1.4
    @kec.pthread    1
    @kec.corecrypto 1.0
    @kec.Libm   1



`
```

Comment: Without knowing what's causing this it will be rather difficult to say whether it is fixed in Big Sur. Does the backtrace always mention com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2 and com.apple.driver.AppleIntelKBLGraphics?

Comment: Yes. Does this point to a GPU problem?